# Why is a Teams Meeting asking some users for PIN?

Tags: windows-10, office365, microsoft-teams

I have two internal Teams users within an organisation that I support who are apparently being asked for a PIN/code when attempting to join a Teams meeting/call, even though other participants are not being asked this.

I am just wondering if anyone has come across this issue before. I've Googled but couldn't find and option for a PIN when creating a meeting.

Comment: Is the PIN part of a two-factor authentication procedure? What exactly is on the screen when your participants are asked for the PIN?

Answer (score 0):

PINs are a per-user setting/value, but are required on a per-meeting basis. PINs are only required in two situations:

1. When the organizer joins a Teams meeting via the dial-in option and is the first to join/when no one else has started/joined the meeting yet from the Teams desktop or web clients. If a participant or presenter has joined the meeting via a client already, the organizer will not be prompted to enter a PIN, even if they join via dial-in.
2. When a Teams meeting is locked/private and the user joining is doing so via dialing in (e.g. as an anonymous user); the user will need to verify they have permission to join the meeting

If a user is prompted for a PIN and doesn't know it, you have several options as a Teams administrator to resolve this issue depending on the factors at hand:

- Instruct these users to join the meeting from a Teams client (either the web or desktop client or even the app on their phone, if they are able to access your tenant from that device).
- Instruct them to wait until someone else has joined the meeting from a Teams client first (in this case, the organizer won't be prompted to enter a PIN when dialing in).
- Reset the user's PIN from the Teams admin center by looking up the account and clicking Reset PIN under the Account section of the user's account page:

  [image: Teams account page showing Reset PIN option circled in red]
- In the Meetings -> Meeting Policies section of the Teams admin center, select the relevant meeting policy applied to the affected users, set the "Let anonymous people start a meeting" policy to "ON":

  [image: Meeting policies section of a given policy indicating the "anonymous organizers" section]

  But bear in mind this will affect the meetings of anyone under this meeting policy (you may well have all users in your tenant under the same policy, such as the default Global or the default AllOn policy).

---

N.B. Resetting the pin is an automated process; you do not get to choose the PIN value. Further, the PIN is only visible via a green banner across the top of the admin center page immediately after you reset it. Once you close the banner, you will not have the ability to see or look up a user's PIN after the fact (though you can reset it an infinite number of times). The user will also receive an automatic e-mail from Microsoft with their new PIN, unless you have that turned off in the Teams Conferencing section:

[image: Example of the email contents a user receives when their PIN is reset]

Answer (score -1):

Reset a user's PIN

1. Using the Microsoft Teams admin center
2. In the left navigation, click Users, and then select the user from the list of available users.
3. Click Edit.
4. Under Audio Conferencing, click Reset PIN.
5. Click Reset.

[What else should you know about PINs?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/reset-the-audio-conferencing-pin-in-teams)